# How to find good parkour shoes

Tags: shoes, parkour

My main question is the title, but I have a couple of details I would like to add.

I would like to be able to buy these shoes in person, because I have a hard time finding shoes that fit and want to try them before purchasing. This probably means that they need to be available from an American chain store, not only sold online or in Europe.

Ideally, I would also like to use these shoes as general walking shoes for shopping and similar activities. They won't get much use in this manner because I have specific shoes for running and work, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright so what I use when I do parkour or free running are adidas classic samba shoes. They are very soft and after some wearing form to your foot in a good manner. I really like them as they have enough support for my arch yet enough grip for vaults and other moves. I have had 2 pairs and neither have ever ripped, i just out grew them. I would highly recommend them for parkour if you like this type of shoe.