# What type of shoes are comfortable as well as don't break as easily for breakdance?

Tags: shoes

When I do flares or footwork with a new shoe it only takes a couple of practices for it to start getting torn in these locations.

[image: Damaged shoe.]

What are some shoe types that are built for breakdance? Shoes that I can use for a longer duration without having to worry about them becoming like this.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the place for purchase recommendations. Please have a look at the site's [on-topic guideline](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking.

Comment: @Alec thanks for the update, I edited my question. Since there isn't a category for breakdance shoes I'm looking for the type of shoes I should buy. Are tennis shoes good? Basketball? Running? My last shoe was running shoes and it tore very easily. I need something different. My question isn't much different from this: https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19147/how-to-find-good-parkour-shoes?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, that seems more reasonable. Re-opened.

Comment: Any answer to this will likely be opinion based.

Comment: Duct tape them up just like skateboarders do.

Comment: I think the question of what aspects of the shoes would make them more durable for breakdancing is fine, and isn't that much different from asking for, say, parkour or jogging. Asking for specific brands feels a bit more like shopping.

Answer (score -1):

You can buy shoes which this part is big[image]

or u can buy " Adidas Gazelle "  brand is so very durable  for bboys.

or while dancing, stick tape on part which torn until the time your feet won't touch the ground in practise.

but do not forget  breaking is dynamic and aggressive dance therefore damaged shoes are the essence of this dance^^